# Adobe flash player default allow using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

While opening **adobe flash player** in IE using **jQuery**, it prompts for **allow/deny**.

Can We make adobe flash player by default Allow using **Java Script/jQuery** so that it will not prompt for the same?

Comment: check this if helps https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/how-to-stop-getting-pop-up-adobe-flash-player/3a352c38-ad95-4cb9-8e4d-c46dd84dcf87

Comment: Thanks Souvik. But i want to make this using javascript/jquery. and from the first time only it should not ask for the same.

Comment: Fortunately/unfortunately that's a securiy feature of modern browsers these days. You can't by pass that using JavaScript. The user of the browser has to do that explicitly.